# Question regarding Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have a question regarding Ito integral, in particular, when I am trying to prove the normality of Ito integral, I encountered the following differential equation I need to solve:
$$dX_{t} = aX_{t}dW_{t},$$
where $a$ is just a constant and $W$ is the standard brownian motion. I solve it and get the solution that $$X_{t}=\int_0^t{aX_{s}dW_{s}}$$But can we get better result than the above one? Since RHS is still depending on $X$. I tried the following, I am wondering if it is correct or not. 
$$\frac{dX_{t}}{X_{t}} = adW_{t}$$Thus we should have $$\int_0^t\frac{dX_{s}}{X_{s}}=\int_0^tadW_{s}$$Then evaluating the integral for RHS and LHS, we have$$LogX_{t}=LogX_{0}+aW_{t}$$
Therefore we should have $$X_{t}=X_{0}e^{aW_{t}}$$
However, I didn't find any reference on if this is correct, did I solve correctly?

Any suggestion will be precious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stochastic differential equation

$$dX_t = a X_t \, dW_t$$

is a linear homogeneous SDE and treated in many books on stochastic differential equations, see e.g. *René L. Schilling/Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*, Chapter 18.

Anyway: Your solution

$$X_t = X_0 e^{a W_t} $$

is not correct. You can check that by applying Itô's formula. The problem is that you cannot solve the **stochastic** differential equation

$$\int_0^t \frac{dX_s}{X_s} = \int_0^t a \, dW_s$$

by replacing the stochastic process $X_t$ by a deterministic $x_t$ and solving it with the usual differential calculus since - by Itô's formula - the stochastic integral does **not** obey these rules. Instead, you have to apply Itô's formula to the function $f(x) := \log x$ and the process $X_t$:

$$\log(X_t)-\log(X_0) = \int_0^t \frac{1}{X_s} \, dX_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \frac{1}{X_s^2} d\langle X \rangle_s = \ldots$$

$\langle X \rangle$ denotes the quadratic variation of $X$.

Comment: thank you. But could you explain what is $d<X>_{s}$ in your last equation?

Comment: @amazonfire $\langle X \rangle$ denotes the quadratic variation of $X$ - in this case $d\langle X \rangle_s$ equals $(aX_s)^2 \, ds$. But hopefully you know about Itô's formula; so that you can simply use the version you are familar with.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, it's just the notation that confuses me, now I got it. So it seems like we cannot do better than $X_{t}=\int_0^t{aX_{s}dW_{s}}$ then, since after using the ito's formula, it does not simplify the problem though

Comment: I think I simplified the problem: please check it is correct. By using the ito lemma, we have $$log(X_{t}) = \int_0^t{\frac{1}{X_{s}}aX_{s}dW_{s}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t{a^{2}}ds$$ Therefore one should get $$log(X_{t}) = aW_{t}-\frac{1}{2}a^{2}t$$ is it correct or not now

Comment: @amazonfire The term $\log(X_0)$ is missing, but apart from that it's correct.